# Customizing jackson deserialization in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize enums to/from lower case by creating a module bean.

```
@Bean
public Module enumModule() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
        @Override
        public JsonDeserializer<Enum> modifyEnumDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config,
                                                             final JavaType type,
                                                             BeanDescription beanDesc,
                                                             final JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
            return new JsonDeserializer<Enum>() {
                @Override
                public Enum deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                    Class<? extends Enum> rawClass = (Class<Enum<?>>) type.getRawClass();
                    return Enum.valueOf(rawClass, jp.getValueAsString().toUpperCase());
                }
            };
        }
    });
    module.addSerializer(Enum.class, new StdSerializer<Enum>(Enum.class) {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Enum value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            jgen.writeString(value.name().toLowerCase());
        }
    });
    return module;
}
```

The serialization works fine but the deserialization code is never called. Also tried using the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` with no success.

Using Spring Boot 1.4.3 and running a test using

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = FooController.class)
```

When creating an `ObjectMapper` manually and registering the module it works as expected.